# Eclipse javadoc view (and hover) blurry text

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-jdt

I am using Eclipse 3.7 on Windows 7, and the text in the *javadoc* view is blurry, no matter what font or size I choose.

[Here](http://postimage.org/image/2y4aufkg4/) you can see screenshot.

The same is happening in the web browser view. In every other view the text is okay.

Is it possible to fix this?

***EDIT:*** Removal if IE9 fixes the problem, [here it looks normal](http://postimage.org/image/1surfzaqs/)

Note 1: To see the problematic text better, ZOOM in on the image.

Note 2: I could remove IE9 only using  *system restore* (use this with care, it tries to resore only *exe* files, dlls, registry, but not others, like conf files. That means, if you have *some-custom-install/hello.exe* and *hello.conf*, and if after the restore point you have updated them, restoring will restore *ONLY* the exe. And if you keep the hello.conf version info or if incompatible between versions, after the restore they will be out of sync).

Comment: Sorry, for me it looks pretty good.

Comment: **Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Java -> Javadoc display font**

Comment: @fnst Are you talking about the screenshot or on your computer?

Comment: @lschin as i've said, changing fonts does not help

Comment: @Op De Cirkel I´m talking about the screenshot. Maybe there are troubles with your monitor?

Comment: Is this a Windows issue? (as in " Control Panel -> Display -> Appearance, and select 'Clear Type' ")

Comment: As it appears, it has to do something with IE9. I've just removed IE9, and eclipse _javadoc_ and _browser view_ look ok now.

Comment: Looks like antialiasing gone wild. Somehow the HTML view forgets to align the letters to whole pixels.

Comment: @Op De Cirkel: Do you consider your problem solved? If so, please post the solution as an answer (and then accept it), so we have fewer unanswered questions here.  (Also, you could cut out a smaller portion of the screenshot and directly embed it into the question, instead of as a link.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: the question is not answered. My comment on IE9 was just a workaround, but not something that is acceptable as solution. If so bad to have open question or the question does not belong here I can close it or delete it.

Comment: No, let it here, maybe someone finds a real solution sometimes (or fixes some bug).

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427315/disable-cleartype-text-anti-aliasing-in-ie9) is the solution.

Comment: Nice work Op De Cirkel. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Comment: @OpDeCirkel Please post the answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To disable anti-aliasing, copy the 2 DLL [dwrite.dll + detoured.dll](http://www.softwareninjas.ca/dwrite-dll-wrapper) next to eclipse.exe, and restart Eclipse.

It works with Eclipse 32-bit edition, but I think it does not work with Eclipse 64-bit edition.