# HTML font edgy and pixellated

Tags: html, fonts, smoothing

I have used `Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif` for font property on my H1 tag.
Below is how it renders.
If you see it closely, it looks very edgy/pixellated. Is there a way to smoothen it?

[image]

UPDATE: Rendering with mingos' solution.

[image]

Comment: You're looking for [anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OS/browser should take care of that. I assume you're using Windows XP with ClearType off or your browser ignores the OS's antialiasing settings (example: [Disable Cleartype (text anti-aliasing) in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427315/disable-cleartype-text-anti-aliasing-in-ie9)). You cannot control that from within your web app, as CSS does not have a means of influencing the browser's text rendering.

Comment: _"CSS does not have a means of influencing the browser's text rendering."_ Sorry, but [that's not quite right](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth-prop).

Comment: Interesting. Is is still a working draft, or is it officially part of CSS3? It doesn't seem to be implemented in modern browsers at all :).

Comment: There's a lot of improvement with your suggestion. Updated original post with font rendering post update.