# How to setup font rendering in MSHTML

Tags: c++, winapi, mshtml

I'm learning to host a browser in my WinApi application using MSHTML and it's IWebBrowser2 and IHTMLDocument2. The first problem is blurry text, the left part of a picture is my app, and the right part is IE:
[image: comparison]

So, how to setup font rendering?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Right now, my app is too huge for posting. I hoped there are some options I can set for MSHTML classes. But ok, I'll try to minimize and post my code.

Comment: Could you please tell us what browser are you using? Whether you are using IE9 browser? If so,  It seems an issue in IE9. This issue occurs because of a design change to how Internet Explorer 9 renders text. By default, IE9 uses sub-pixel positioned ClearType to render text by using DirectWrite. You could try to disable ClearType. For more details I suggest you could refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427315/disable-cleartype-text-anti-aliasing-in-ie9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your screen setting looks like 150% scaling so make sure that application is marked as DPI aware (edit manifest or select option in IDE).
2. In `IDocHostUIHandler::GetHostInfo` implementation add `DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE` to `dwFlags`.

```
HRESULT DocHostUIHandler::GetHostInfo( DOCHOSTUIINFO* pInfo )
{
    pInfo->cbSize = sizeof(DOCHOSTUIINFO);
    pInfo->dwFlags =
            DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER
            | DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE
            | DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_SCRIPT_INACTIVE;
    pInfo->dwDoubleClick = DOCHOSTUIDBLCLK_DEFAULT;
    return S_OK;
}
```

3. Change emulated IE version by setting registry key (not essential for high DPI, rather for better CSS support).

```
BOOL FixIeCompatMode()
{
    DWORD fix_version = 11001;

    // Get full path to application
    WCHAR app_path[ PATH_MAX ];
    DWORD result = GetModuleFileName( NULL, app_path, PATH_MAX );
    if ( result == 0 || result == PATH_MAX )
        return FALSE;

    // Find application name part (without path)
    WCHAR* app_name = app_path + wcslen( app_path );
    while ( app_name > app_path && app_name[ -1 ] != '\\' )
        --app_name;

    // Create or open FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key
    HKEY hKey;
    WCHAR* reg_path = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
    if ( RegCreateKey( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_path, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS )
        return FALSE;

    // Add registy entry for our application e.g
    // DisplayHTML.exe = 11001
    // You can check it (or delete) with regedit
    BOOL set = RegSetValueEx(
                 hKey,
                 app_name,
                 0,
                 REG_DWORD,
                 (void*)&fix_version,
                 sizeof(fix_version) ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    RegCloseKey( hKey );
    return set;
}

// Somewhere in your startup code (before creating WebView)
FixIeCompatMode();
```

**Edit:**

`FixIeCompatMode` sets WebBrowser emulation mode. Depending on value assigned to `fix_version` WebBrowser emulates different versions of IE.

[Internet Feature Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#browser-emulation)

> - **11001**: Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
> - **11000**: IE11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 edge mode. Default value for IE11.
> - **10001**: Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
> - **10000**: Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
> - **9999**: Windows Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
> - **9000**: Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9. In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
> - **8888**: Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
> - **8000**: Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8. Important  In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
> - **7000**: Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.

[What Happens if I Set the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Document Mode Value Higher than the IE Version on the Client?](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/archive/blogs/patricka/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility#what-happens-if-i-set-the-feature_browser_emulation-document-mode-value-higher-than-the-ie-version-on-the-client)

> Obviously, the browser control can only support a document mode that
> is less than or equal to the IE version installed on the client.
> Using the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key works best for enterprise line
> of business apps where there is a deployed and support version of the
> browser. **In the case you set the value to a browser mode that is a
> higher version than the browser version installed on the client, the
> browser control will choose the highest document mode available**.

If `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` is omitted some !DOCTYPE directives (e.g `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`) could activate old IE 7.0 emulation with many drawbacks (e.g. worse CSS support).

You can check it (or delete) with regedit.
[image: regedit browser emulation]

Comment: Thanks! For simplicity I call ```SetProcessDPIAware()``` instead of adding DPIAware into manifest file, also I added the ```DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE``` flag in ```GetHostInfo()```. And it works. But could you please explain a little bit, what your third point does, and why it's needed?

Comment: @qloq Added link and quoted essential part.